# What is the difference between running npx eslint and npx?

Tags: node.js, npm, eslint, npx

I am using npm 8.5.0 and node v16.14.2 on a big project. When I run eslint, I can choose to run it without npx, or I can run it with npx. There doesn't seem to be any difference. I'm writing some npm scripts that run eslint and I don't know whether to write `npx eslint` or `eslint`.
What is the difference between running `npx eslint` and `eslint`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`npx` will download and run the package and is meant for interactive use where you just want to use a tool from the npm registry.

You shouldn't use it in your `package.json`'s `scripts` section; instead just make sure the desired version of `eslint` is in your package's dev dependencies and use `"eslint"` in the scripts, so you're certain to use the correct version.